# Not able to update <version> property from .nuspec file

Tags: .net-core, nuget

My .nuspec file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
   <metadata>
      <id>name-id</id>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <authors>author name</authors>
      <description>desc</description>   
  </metadata>   

</package>
```

When I do dotnet pack on this then I do get a package which is named packagename.2.0.0.nupkg. I need to override that property and I am using `dotnet cli` for this. I did stumple upon a not very well documented option here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x

I am doing following command `dotnet pack -p:version=1.0` and expecting it to be overridden to 1.0 but the package is still getting created as 2.0.0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you use a .nuspec file when you are running `dotnet pack`? That's a wrong approach IMHO as the new SDK based projects can go without such files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to override from .nuspec is using following switch in `dotnet pack`

`-p:versionSuffix=${whatever-value-you-want-to-pass}`

which would effectively override .nuspec whereever there is `$versionSuffix$`. Now if we want to override the metadata inside .nuspec and .nuspec looks like following:

`<version>$versionSuffix$</version>` and you pass in `dotnet pack your-project-name.csproj -p:versionSuffix={some-variable}` then it would override version inside .nuspec with value of `some-variable`

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `nuspec` with NuGet's MSBuild pack target (the `dotnet pack` command is just an alias for `dotnet msbuild -t:pack`), it overrides everything else. In fact, I believe that it doesn't use any MSBuild properies, so the `nuspec` must be entirely self-contained and complete.

As [NuGet's docs on creating a package with the dotnet cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli) says, package metadata is specified in the project file, [full list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target). If you get rid of your `nuspec`, then passing in a version though a msbuild property will work.